# I am sending the directories then i got some wierd problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is my code:-

```js
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.get("/", function (req,res) {
   res.send("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
   res.send(__dirname + '\\index.html');
});
    
app.listen(3000, function () {
   console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
   
});
```

[image]

I was expecting to run code properly and the file properly send to given location

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow - it's a great platform. Unfortunately this question is too generic, please make it more specific and update the title.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You are calling `res.send` twice but you cannot send two responses for one request. Remove the first `res.send` call and you should be fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

Comment: Now I had try that but still not working

Comment: @MonsterSkull What exactly did you try? Is the error the same or did it change?

Comment: like Palladium02 said, remove the `res.send("<h1>Hello World</h1>");`

Comment: @MonsterSkull you have 2 `.send` methods but you can only send 1 response

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the first `res.send` line

```
res.send("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
```

because the `.send` method sends an argument value, already held in memory, back to the browser, and you can't reply (send a response) to the same request twice. The error is generated for the *second* send and is worded "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client".

Then change the second `send` to

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + '\\index.html');
```

to have Express read the index file and send it to the client using the `sendFile` method.

I recommend looking up and reading [Express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html) when in doubt - take the link, select "response" in the left hand column and scroll down for `res.send` and `res.sendFile` entries.